# Marked an edit as Rejected, what happens next?

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/what-are-the-most-common-cockpit-system-and-instrument-failures-in-small-airplan), an edit was proposed which I reviewed and marked to reject, as I didn't see any improvement while it introduced something entirely outside of all English grammar/vocabulary that I'm aware of (a "reliant instrument"). At about the same time, another user reviewed and approved the edit, and it is now visible -- i.e. the edit has been accepted & applied.

In a case like this, does the Reject vote accomplish anything different that skipping the review? Shouldn't the presence of a reject vote at least raise the bar to get approval - say, with one Reject vote cast, two Approve votes would be needed in order to approve the edit?

Or did the other user & I just hit some moment in time where things got considered by the server simultaneously & the Approve got applied first?

Comment: It actually did receive two approve votes in addition to your reject vote, with the last approve vote happening after yours.

Comment: Oh, okay. I didn't see the 1st approve vote, evidently. Makes more sense knowing that it is there. How many Approve votes would have been needed if I had not voted to Reject?

Comment: @RalphJ see my edited answer.  The edit needs 2 approve votes regardless of whether it got a reject vote or not. The first of accept or reject to get 2 votes wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [review of that suggested edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13538) received two approvals and one reject (yours) which was enough to let it through. For sites other than stack overflow the threshold to accept or reject edits is 2 votes.  The first option to get 2 votes determines the outcome of the review. If you had accepted the edit, it would have gone through with your vote and if the third vote was a reject it would have been rejected.  The reject isn't meaningless but you also can't act unilaterally with it, you need one additional reject vote (just as acceptance won't happen with only one vote).  Only diamond moderators and the post author can accept/reject edits with a sole binding vote.

In my opinion the edit looks good though I agree that "reliant instruments" is not a great verbiage change.  I probably would have edited that part and kept the rest of the edit rather than rejecting the whole thing.

What to do next?  If you strongly dislike the edit you can roll it back, or more appropriately you can just edit the part that you don't like.  You have enough rep that you can directly edit and it will not go through the queue.  The other alternatives are to ignore it or to post a meta Q about like this one.

Comment: I'm not overly concerned about the wording of the question; I just wondered about the process. Does 2-1 voting to approve work the same as 2-0? So until the second Reject vote comes in, the first Reject vote doesn't raise the threshold of 2 Approve votes needed? Or is it more complicated than just numbers of votes? (Leaving out what the diamond mods can do, obviously.)

Comment: @RalphJ on stack overflow the threshold is 3 votes and on any other site (e.g. this one) it is 2 votes.  So on aviation the first of accept or reject to get 2 votes determines the outcome of the review.